# Comparing two states of a puzzle

Tags: c++11, c++14

How can I compare two states of 8 puzzles, given that "one state is less than
another state if and only if the value in the center cell of the first state is less than the value in the center cell of the second state." The states are in 3*3 puzzle or board and the states are stored in queues(as required by the question).

I am trying with the overloading operator < . But its not working. I have attached some parts of my coding here. Really be helpful if anyone can help!

```
#ifndef STATE_H_INCLUDED
#define STATE_H_INCLUDED

const int BOARDSIZE = 3;
const int Size=1;

class State
{
private:
    int grid[BOARDSIZE][BOARDSIZE];
public:
    State() {
        for( int i=0;i<BOARDSIZE;i++){
            for( int j=0;j<BOARDSIZE;j++){
                cin >> grid[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    State(const State& s) {
        for(int i=0;i<BOARDSIZE;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<BOARDSIZE;j++)
                grid[i][j] = s.getValue(i,j);
    }

    bool operator <(State s) const {//problem is probably somewhere here
        if(grid[1][1] < s.getValue(1,1));
            return false;
        return true;
    }
};
```

And following is the `.cpp`:

```
while (!q.empty()){
    q.front().printBoard();

    if(q.front()<p){
        cout<<"Less than previous!"<<endl;
        break;
    }

    q.pop();

    cout<<endl;
}
```

Part of the main question is :

Overload operator < so that one state is less than
another state if and only if the value in the center cell of the first state is less than the
value in the center cell of the second state. For instance,

```
7 0 5       0 1 3
1 3 8  <    4 6 5
4 6 2       7 2 8
```

Write a class driver to test the overloaded comparison operator.
Hint: The operator< function must be const, which looks like:
bool operator<(State s) const

Comment: ***I am trying with the overloading operator < . But its not working.*** What do you mean by that? Please be more precise. Post some error codes or explain what you expect and what the actual result looks like.

Comment: Hi,
I have updated the question, hope it may clarify you.
Basically I have to compare the two states of a board. User enters the first state and the second state is created through permutation. Now I have to compare the center cell that means the center row of two states to find out which one is greater. TIA

Comment: *user input is first state and the permuted one is the other state.

Comment: Your implementation of operator< is inverted. grid will be the left-hand side of the comparison so you want to return true if grid[1][1] < s.getValue(1,1).

Also you probably want to pass in const ref into your comparator

Comment: `if(grid[1][1] < s.getValue(1,1));` should use either the array access convention or the member function call inn both accesses. You can access private members of another object of the same class in the comparison operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `operator<` doesn't satisfy the requirements of [Compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare), because `s < s` returns `true`. Assuming that `q` in your snippet is a `std::priority_queue<State>`, then your program is ill-formed.

You probably mean to have

```
bool State::operator<(const State & rhs)
{ return grid[1][1] < rhs.grid[1][1]; }
```

If you want the front of the queue to be the minimum element, they you instead should define it as a `std::priority_queue<State, std::vector<State>, std::greater<State>>`, and define

```
bool State::operator>(const State & rhs)
{ return grid[1][1] > rhs.grid[1][1]; }
```

rather than have an inverted meaning `<`

Comment: Hi,
its in just fifo queue.